# Ignoring or redefining GCC Standard Predefined Macros

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, c-preprocessor, flags

Is it possible to tell GCC to compile the source code, and ignore macros like `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` , etc, etc, or redefine them to expand into let's say - an empty string?

Comment: really a bad idea, why would you want this so? A lot of code (including system headers) will depend on these to do the right thing. This is just looking for trouble.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? because: 1. C standard prohibits redefining/undefining them 2. Replacing `__LINE__` with like `0` or `-1` would look awkward (It's an integer value and you have to give something, unlike empty string for `__FILE__`) 3. Their primary purpose *is* to help debug (If you don't want them, why use them in the first place?). So it seems the only way is to re-write your code if you don't want them or better keep them!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with any macro you can just use:

```
#undef __LINE__
#undef __FILE__
```

and then you can redefine them.

You can also pass `-U macroname` to undef a macro name and `-D macroname=definition` to define a macro name to the `gcc` options.

Note that, as indicated in another answer, undefining or redefining `__LINE__` or `__FILE__` in C invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: I suspect doing so provokes UB. Please see my answer on this.

Comment: @alk but I think the relevant quote is this one: *(c99, 6.10.8p4)  "None of these macro names, nor the identifier defined, shall be the subject of a #define or a #undef preprocessing directive.*

Comment: Hm, yes, found this too .. but UB isn't mentioned in this context.

Comment: @alk violation of a shall requirement that is not a constraint in C invokes UB, see C99, 4.p2

Comment: It would probably be better if it'd be a constraint violation. Implementing a check for that at compilation time should not be big deal.

Comment: @alk I see that the current C standard is C11. Is C99 accurate/up-to-date enough to be used in most cases? P.S. I don't want to spend $30 USD on the new standard.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey: I doubt there are many essential changes (not additions) from C99 to C11 which aren't backward compatible. However this is an assumption of mine ... - Details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29